# python how to convert str to unicode ( persion )?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, decode, persian

this string is subject of a mail. I get this string by imaplib.
type of this string is "str".

thank you!

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import imaplib
from email.parser import HeaderParser

conn = imaplib.IMAP4('imap.gmail.com')
conn.login('myuser', 'my_pass')
conn.select()
conn.search(None, 'ALL')  # returns a nice list of messages...

data = conn.fetch(1, '(BODY[HEADER])')

header_data = data[1][0][1]

parser = HeaderParser()
msg = parser.parsestr(header_data)
print repr(msg['subject'].decode('utf-8'))
```

result:

```
u'=?UTF-8?B?V2VsY29tZSB0byBBdGxhc01haWw=?='
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `decode_header` and `make_header` functions from the [`email.header`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.header.html) package to process the header, then convert the header object to unicode:

```
from email.header import make_header, decode_header
header = make_header(decode_header(msg['subject']))
unicode_header = unicode(header)
print repr(unicode_header)  # prints: u'Welcome to AtlasMail'
```

Comment: It's absolutely correct but just for English words. It doesn't work for Persian words :(

Comment: If the header was encoded correctly it should work, but that depends on the client that generated the message.

Answer (score -1):

The encoding of non ascii characterers in an e-mail subject is decribed at [RFC-1342](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1342) -
as you can see there, your utf-8 bytes are, in this case, base 64 encoded.

SO, to actually read this, you could do something along:

```
import base64, quopri
try:
    encoding, enc_type, subject = msg["subject"].split("?", 2)
except ValueError:
    subject = msg["subject"].decode("utf-8")
    enc_type = "N/A"
if enc_type == "B":
    subject = base64.decodestring(subject).decode(encoding.lower())
elif enc_type == "Q":
    subject = quopri.decodestring(subject).decode(encoding.lower())
```

Comment: not enough, completed code is: def convert_to_unicode(string):
    print string
    list_word = string.split()
    result = ''
    for word in list_word:
        try:
            a, encoding, enc_type, subject, b = word.split("?")
        except ValueError:
            subject = msg["subject"].decode("utf-8")
            enc_type = "N/A"
        if enc_type == "B":
            subject = base64.decodestring(subject).decode(encoding.lower())
        elif enc_type == "Q":
            subject = quopri.decodestring(subject).decode(encoding.lower())
        result += subject + ' '
    return result